# Xamarin Forms crash when debugging

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to debugging an Xamarin Forms application but when i start the debug it's open and close the application and stop the debugger.
[image: Bug]

I'm Using VS2015 and all updates of Xamarin forms and supports

Comment: No, it's not resolved.

Comment: I have update my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: 
"When i used a CRUD project with references in Android Project, if i have system.Drawing it's not build because the Android Project not accept System.Drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an error with your linked libaries. Try this:

1. Close the solution
2. Delete the whole content of the Packages folder (there are the referenced Nuget libaries)
3. Open the solution again
4. Build again (Nuget will get the libaries again based on the packages.config)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for [Pavendhan Kumar's advice](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/125756/assembly-loader-probing-location-39syncfusion-sfautocomplete-xforms-android39).

1. You could try clearing bin,obj folders and to uninstall previously installed app with this name, sometimes the uninstalled app have an entry at this location with its namespace.
2. Also try cancelling "`Use shared runtime option`" under android `Properties->Android Options->cancel` in project file.

**EDIT** :

You could enable diagnostic logging and then check which reference leads to the wrong assembly.

```
Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> Choose Diagnostic logging
```